# How to extract specific content using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, series

Consider the following data

```
Non-removable Li-Po 2870 mAh battery
Non-removable Li-Po 5910 mAh battery (A3-A20-K1AY)
Non-removable Li-Po 1810 mAh battery (6.9 Wh)
```

I would like to extract the mAh battery numeric value from this like below

```
2870
5910
1810
```

I tried using

```
def func(x):
  # Split array
  ar = x.split(' mAh')
```

but i dont get what do i need to return

Comment: Its a dataframe this is just a part of data

Comment: If it is just a sample, what is the **constant** context here that can help detect the number? Is it always an integer value? Is there always `Li-Po` before the number? Is there always `mAh` after it? Note that meW's suggestion may overmatch while Jan's solution may undermatch, it depends on what requirements you want to meet here. Please be specific when it comes to regex questions.

Comment: i know that its just the column had 1200 unique values i just needed some hint how would i be able to do this

Comment: You have two below.

Comment: yeah! used them both for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Considering the value always lie between `LiPo` and `mAh`, use `extract`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Non-removable Li-Po 2870 mAh battery',
                           'Non-removable Li-Po 5910 mAh battery (A3-A20-K1AY)',
                           'Non-removable Li-Po 1810 mAh battery (6.9 Wh)']})
df.col.str.extract('Li-Po (.*) mAh')

      0
0  2870
1  5910
2  1810
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to always be the first number, so you might use

```
^\D*(\d+)
```

As in

```
df.column_in_question_here.str.extract('^\D*(\d+)')
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yyqGJR/1/) for the expression.